# How to find the matrices of the following linear maps for the given bases

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree no greater than $2$.

Let $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and $\{e_1^{'}, e_2^{'},e_3^{'}\}$ be the bases $\{1, x, x^2\}$ and $\{(1+x), (1+x^2), (1+x)^2\}$ respectively.

Write down the matrices of the linear maps $e_i$ to $e_i^{'}$ and $e_i^{'}$ to $e_i$.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Note $e_1' = e_1 + e_2$, $e_2' = e_1 + e_3$ and $e_3'= e_1 + 2 e_2 + e_3$.

Thus, the map from the ' basis to the non ' basis is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ (if you multiply on the right by $e_1'= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, you get $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ which is $e_1'$ in the non ' coordinates. Similar for $e_2',e_3'$).

You can invert this to get the reverse transformation.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful